# Spring Restfull Jax-RS annotation support

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

I have following class and web.xml files.  Does spring framework supports jax-rs annotation such as `@PATH`, and `@PUT`, `@Consumes`...etc.

In other word can I use `@PATH` instead of `@RequestMapping`

**Java:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Controller
@Path("/register")
public class RegisterServices {
    @PUT
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public Response create(@Context HttpServletRequest requestContex,
                           @HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization, 
                           String xMsisdn, String param) {}
}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot use `javax.ws.*` annotations in spring. You can use something like `resteasy` with spring. It is rather easy. If you need I can provide with an example. (Jersey and CXF has good JAX-RS implementations too.)

AFAIK Springsource has no idea to provide an implementation to JAX-RS. So if you want to use the features described in JAX-RS you will not get it directly from spring. But you can develop a rest web service using spring. That's a different story. A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007164/spring-mvc-rest-is-not-jax-rs-compliant-does-it-matter) was found on SO on that.

### Update

Depending on PaulNUK's answer below, I need to clarify my answer. End of the day rest is a specification, and someone needs to implement it in first place.

Question clearly asks, whether we **can replace the annotations, you cant do it**, unless you add an external dependency like **Jersey to your classpath**. That case implementation is provided by Jersey.

Therefore you would never be able to use spring implemented JAX-RS annotation ever.

Comment: +1 Good answer! Spring also integrates with Jersey which is the reference implementation of JAX-RS

Comment: ın that case  I think @PATH annotation is handled by Jersey API

Comment: Yes it does. But as with RestEasy integration, you can inject Spring services into Jersey controllers. As Maleenc pointed out, there is no Spring implementation of JAX-RS. The best you can do is integration a JAX-RS implementation (such as Jersey or RestEasy) with Spring to provide a Spring "backend" to the JAX-RS frontend

Comment: Sorry this is wrong - you can use javax,ws annotations in Spring. See my answer below. The Spring boot example is using multiple javax.ws annotations.

Answer (score 7):

Just put your JAX-RS (I'm using Jersey 2) annotations on a class, annotate that class with @Component to make it a Spring bean, and you have full JAX-RS support with Spring dependency injection.

So Spring hasn't reinvented the wheel by implementing JAX-RS itself, but integrates very easily with Jersey for example.

Here's a simple Spring boot example:

http://spring.io/blog/2014/11/23/bootiful-java-ee-support-in-spring-boot-1-2

Comment: You need spring-boot-starter-jersey dependency in the classpath. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey

Answer (score 3):

If you want to develop the webservices using only Spring framework then Spring provides Spring MVC. Spring MVC has its own set of annotations. For e.g. "@RequestMapping". Spring MVC doesn't even adhere to the JAX-RS principles.

There are various opensource frameworks (like Jersey) which supports "JAX-RS" and can be integrated with Spring.

However, just in case you want to compare the Spring MVC with Jersey then below is the comparison. I personally support Jersey over SPring MVC as Spring MVC is not originally meant for webservices but for UI application.

1. Same relative paths in multiple @Controllers not supported
2. @ExceptionHandler is controller-centric
3. Standard content negotiation can’t respond with a fixed response type (SPR-6937)
4. JSR 303 bean validation not applied in @Controllers (SPR-6928, scheduled for 3.1)
5. Formatting responses (i.e. Date) not working using Spring formatter annotations
6. You cannot return a bean from an exception handler and expect it to be automatically serialized to xml or json based on the incoming accept header.

HTH...