# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet - Context Component Scan not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on an existing code base, which is using Hibernate and Spring. I have written a Controller class, but when I am trying to see the JSON response  in the browser, I get a 404 - Page Not Found exception.  However, the other existing Controller classes are working in the same manner, but am not able to figure out why ? Sorry, am very new to  Spring, and am sure must be missing something silly.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have other controllers that are working. What annotation do they use? Also Controller? I think you might have a problem with your component scan definition in the context file.

Comment: @Koby : Please see the edit above

Comment: Try defining your method as public, seems like it is defined as package-private.

Comment: @Koby : It worked. thanks so much. Please post this as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your controller method is defined as package-private. Change the controller method to public.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using JAX-RS annotations with Spring. Apparently you can't do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543692/spring-restfull-jax-rs-annotation-support). `@RequestMapping` and `@RestController` are the recommended annotations for what you want to do. Check the [Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) for a good example.