# Use spring bean as Jax-RS resource

Tags: spring, jersey-2.0

I would like to know if it's possible to instantiate a bean in Spring using Java based configuration (providing all the Jax-RS annotations, @Path and so on.. ) , and then tell Jersey to use that bean as resource, avoiding Jersey to instantiate a new class.

Edit: if possible I would like to avoid annotating my bean with @Component or @Service like in the answers you linked here (thanks for prompt reaction!)

Thanks in advance
Giulio

Comment: Yes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543692/spring-restfull-jax-rs-annotation-support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Restfull Jax-RS annotation support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543692/spring-restfull-jax-rs-annotation-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578498/554117) was very helpful:

I found out that @Component annotation on the bean/resource (created via Java Config) is needed to make Jersey correctly use the Spring instantiated bean, avoiding it to create a new instance.

Thanks for the support :)