# Spring REST WS : jersey vs resteasy vs restlet vs apache cxf vs Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, spring-ws

I am planning to build a ResT full web service using spring 4 and java 7 for a complex highly performance oriented application. After researching i have found following options.

1. Spring REST WS (using Jackson). [Example](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program)
2. Spring + Jersey. [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/)
3. Spring + Resteasy. [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/)
4. Spring + Apache CFX. [Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/developing-restful-services-using-apache-cxf.html)
5. Spring + Restlet. [Example](https://www.workreloaded.com/2012/07/spring-restlet-integration-a-complete-example/)

My choice was Spring WS but Spring MVC REST is not JAX-RS compliant (if i am not wrong). **Source -** [Spring MVC REST is not JAX-RS compliant. Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007164/spring-mvc-rest-is-not-jax-rs-compliant-does-it-matter)

**Question:**

- Does it matter using it as non JAX-RS compliant??
- Do i need to take additional steps to make it JAX-RS compliant ??
- Security point of view what are the steps i need to take care ?
- Any best prectices ?

Answer (score 9):

Well I guess it always depends on our needs and how we feel we can manage changes and new frameworks releases
Personally I'd use the first solution Spring REST WS (using Jackson) above all because it's totally integrated in spring application framework and you must not add (and sometimes fight) with third parties libs; and believe me this is really a good thing

Morever I don't see any great advantage in adding other JAX-WS implementation except to increase the project complexity

And the last....by adding third party libs you not nly have to know good Spring, but also the other libraries you use and not all the developers are able and can learn new technologies....at least this is my opinion and my experience :)

Comment: Thank you. I do feel the same way and had chosen it Spring Rest WS. but since it dosnt follow JAX-RS compliant i was wondering if it is right way of doing it or i need to take any additional steps ?

Comment: well so far...I used it with no additional steps